# LLVM - How to make a nested function see an outside function's variables

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to write a compiler for a language that supports nested functions, for example:

```
func a()
   int x;
   func b()
      int y;
      {
       // code of func b - both x and y are visible here
      }
   {
    // code of func a - only x is visible here
   }
```

I am using LLVM API in c++ to compile the code. My problem is that I don't know how to make variable x visible in function b, since to my knowledge llvm does not support nested function. The way I am declaring variable as of now is this function:

```cpp
static AllocaInst *CreateEntryBlockAlloca(Function *TheFunction, const std::string &VarName, Type *T) {
    IRBuilder<> TmpB(&TheFunction->getEntryBlock(), TheFunction->getEntryBlock().begin());
    return TmpB.CreateAlloca(T, 0, VarName.c_str());
}
```

As shown in the llvm tutorial https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl07.html#adjusting-existing-variables-for-mutation.
When using this declaration and trying to use an outside variable in a nested function this error pops up: *Instruction does not dominate all uses!*.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: c++ doesn't support nested function definitions besides lambda function definitions. It's unclear what you're after.

Comment: That isn't a supported C++ programming practice.  If you want to access a variable in a parent function, pass a reference to it.

Comment: I am trying to compile the code in the example(with functions a and b) to llvm code (not sure if that's what is called), to be compiled with ```llc```. But because llvm is a c like language and doesn't support nested functions I need another way to make variable ```x``` visible and accessible in function ```b```. Global variables would be a way, but I don't think it is really viable to use them.

Comment: @JohnFikioris so this is what actual compilers do: they convert such nested functions into a class with a constructor and a method (being the actual function body). The constructor takes a reference (or value, depends) to the outer variable and stores it in the object. Then the code is transformed into "create object" and "call method" instructions. That's what you need to implement.

Comment: @freakish Do you have any suggestions on how to do that ?

Comment: @JohnFikioris You may refer to a lambda capturing variables in such case as mentioned. You cannot change the language parsing fundamentally fpr the llvm frontend.

Comment: @freakish So you are basically saying to pass every outer variable as a parameter to the inner function when called.

Comment: @JohnFikioris yes, sort of. Depending on what you need having a separate struct will allow you to store "inline functions" and opens more possibilities. I've made my comment into an answer.

Comment: I think some Pascal compilers, to support this, did something along the lines of: first make sure that all local variables are "spilled" to the stack in a fixed layout before the inner function is called, then pass a pointer to the outer function's stack frame as an implicit parameter of the inner function.  (And then for multiple-level nesting of functions, you would need to have some mechanism to chain from one stack frame to an outer layer, or else pass implicit pointers to each outer stack frame as determined by the lexical code structure.)

Comment: Yes, my language is kinda like pascal, but I think freakish's answer is easier to implement.

Comment: @JohnFikioris There is another way of dealing with nested functions depending on how your language is designed. For example Python compiles nested functions on the fly. Meaning it stores its body code somewhere and once `a()` is executed it builds the nested function inside it (and binds all references on the fly). This is arguably simplier. But requires embedding the compiler (possibly only the final IL compiler) inside runtime. You lose some performance plus some optimizations may be impossible with this approach. One of the reasons why most scripting languages are slow.

Comment: Also you would have to slightly redesign your language because such functions are no longer easily convertible to llvm functions. They are now (runtime) objects with source code.

Comment: It's for my compiler course so I don't really get a say :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM does support structs, right? So here's what typical compilers do.

You need to create an anonymous struct with fields generated from **every** outer variable you reference. Then you create an anonymous function corresponding to `b()` that takes that struct as argument and operates on it. Basically you turn `b()` into a regular top-level function. Finally you transform `a()` code so that it creates the struct instance and calls the anonymous function. At this point further optimizations are possible. Be prepared: this is not easy at all, possibly a very advanced topic for code transformations.

For example

```
func a()
   int x = 1;
   func b() {
      return x+1;
   }
   return b() + 2;
}
```

becomes

```
struct tmp {
    int tmpx;  // reference or value?
}
func tmp_b(tmp& instance) {
    instance.tmpx += 1;
    return instance.tmpx;
}
func a() {
    int x = 1;
    tmp instance(tmpx = x);  // should it go by reference or value?
    return tmp_b(instance) + 2;
}
```

As an alternative you can convert `b()` into `b(int x)` top-level function. But that approach is less flexible IMO. Or depending on context utilize both approaches, why not.

Note that all of that can probably be simplified if your language supports proper classes with methods and/or operator (in this case call operator) overloading.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a supported capability in C++.

If you are looking to access a variable in this way from a nested or any other function, pass a reference to it. :)

Comment: The code I am trying to compile isn't C++. I am using the LLVM API to create the compiled executable. The language that I want to compile supports nested functions.

Comment: Ah... You have this tagged as a C++ question.  I misread what you were asking.